# Convert Excel VBA (Macro) to VBScript

Tags: vba, excel, vbscript

I have an excel macro like the one below:

```vb
Sub terst1()
    Dim rindex As Long
    Dim saItem() As String
    Dim Arr() As String
    Dim Res() As String
    Dim m As Long, i As Long
    Dim InputRng As Range, OutRng As Range

    For rindex = Cells(Rows.Count, "E").End(xlUp).Row To 1 Step -1
        If InStr(Cells(rindex, "E").Value, ";") > 0 Then
            Arr = VBA.Split(Cells(rindex, "E").Value, ";#")
            m = UBound(Arr) \ 2
            ReDim Preserve Res(m)

            For i = 0 To m
                Res(i) = Arr(i * 2)
            Next

            Rows(rindex + 1 & ":" & rindex + UBound(Res)).Insert
            Cells(rindex, "E").Resize(UBound(Res) + 1).Value = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(Res)
        End If
    Next rindex
End Sub
```

I want to convert the above macro into VBScript where the file path should be part of code.

I have below VBScript but it is giving me only first name and rest are skipped.

```vb
Dim c
Dim d

Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
Set objWorkbook = objExcel.Workbooks.Open("D:\test4.xlsm")

objExcel.Visible = True
objExcel.displayalerts = false

Set objExcel2 = CreateObject("Excel.Application")

strPathExcel = "C:\Users\Desktop\test4.xlsx"
objExcel2.Workbooks.open strPathExcel 

Set oSheet = objExcel2.ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(1)

a = 2
i = 2
j = 2

Do Until objExcel.Cells(a, 1).Value = ""
    c = 0
    d = 0

    Do Until c = objExcel.Cells(j, 3).Value
        inputText=objExcel.Cells(j, 5).Value
        oSheet.Cells(i,3).Value = split(inputText,";#")

        c = c + 1
        d = d + 1
    Loop

    i = i + 1   
    a = a + 1
    j = j + 1
Loop

objExcel.Save
objExcel2.Save

objExcel.Quit
objExcel2.Quit
```

Comment: SO is not a free translation service. What have you tried, and what *specific* problem do you need help with? For pointers about translating VBA to VBScript see [my blog](http://sdb.planetcobalt.net/vba2vbs.shtml).

Comment: i tried to convert that by removing the data types and all but it doesnt work

Comment: "Doesn't work" is an insufficient problem description. Show us what you tried and what error you got from it.

Comment: i have this type of data [Pankaj sharma;#234;#khushal verma;#786;#parul datta;#456;#]     i want data : pankaj sharma

                                                                             khushal verma  in seperate cells one below one   but above code is a macros i want to convert it into vb script

Comment: This is probably a bigger request than you realize. It's not that it's a ton of work to convert, but it's complicated. VBS doesn't have built in Excel functionality, so you have to open an Excel Application Object, then you have to open the workbook, point to the right worksheet, and all that. Much of your code will need to be changed to refer to the Excel object and it's child objects. You should start by Googling "Open an excel workbook in VBscript" and work from there.

Comment: Do you know [*Late Binding*](http://peltiertech.com/Excel/EarlyLateBinding.html). If you wish to convert this into a [tag:vbscript] then you need to create an instance of the Excel Application. Very similar when you use Late Binding across MS Application. Start there and edit your post if you got stuck somewhere.

Answer (score 2):

As I've commented, it is very similar when you try to use *Late Binding*.
To give you an example consider this code:

```
Sub Test()
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Set wb = Workbooks.Open("C:\User\Desktop\Sample.xlsm")

    Application.Run "MyMacro"
    wb.Save
    wb.Close
End Sub
```

So above VBA opens a file, runs a macro within that file then saves and closes it.
So in VBScript, the equivalent would be:

```
Dim XLapp
Dim XLwb

Set XLapp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
Set XLwb = XLapp.Worksbooks.Open("C:\User\Desktop\Sample.xlsm")

XLapp.Run "MyMacro"
XLwb.Save
XLwb.Close
XLapp.Quit
```

This is not a direct answer but a hint to give you an idea on how it is done.
I have not explored which functionalities in VBA are supported in VBScript so you need to explore on that as well.

**Important:** Now, as you can see, you can actually write most of your routine within the workbook and then use above code to run it. That is the intent of why I gave you this example cause I have done this in the past as well :)